# Paragraph in a div should be hidden

Tags: html, css

I am having a dynamic widget on my website that displays the following structure when the website is loaded:

```
<div id="testdiv">
  <h2>a Headline</h2>
  <p>This paragraph should be hidden.</p>
</div>
```

How can i hide the paragraph? I have no idea because the generated paragraph has no class or id to hide with css (i tried `<sytle>#testdiv.p{visibility:hidden !important}</style>` without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.p` means class `p`. `#testdiv.p` means element with id "testdiv" *and* class name "p". `p` means tag, space after `#testdiv` means child element. So it should be:

```css
#testdiv p {
  display: none;
}
```

You also probably better off with `display: none`. Use `visibility` if you want `p` invisible but still taking up space.